# Display desired url of webpage inline with replacement of html code like Google Translate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-applications

I want to make app which will switch vocabulary in desired url of webpage Japanese to English.
But firstable I want start form just simply display desired url of webpage inline lust like Google Translate.([See here](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=ja&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=ja&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fringo-12.com&edit-text=&act=url))

I tried to use open-uri library, and get html from webpage, and display it with code below.

Controller:

```
def submit
    require 'open-uri'

    charset = nil
    @html = open(params[:url]) do |f|
      charset = f.charset
      f.read
    end
end
```

View:

```
<%= @html.html_safe %>
```

But I have problem with this, which simply won't load Images and some stylesheets in page.
Any way to display image and css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are displaying HTML from another domain on your domain, then any relative URLs used in the HTML (links, scripts, styles, etc.) aren't going to correspond with files that exist on your domain. You are going to have to parse the HTML and either expand the URLs to full URLs that point to the original domain (easier) OR you are going to have to download all the content to your domain using the same path structure.

Example:

To display an image, a site (example.com) could use any of the following src attributes:

```
<img src="http://example.com/images/logo.jpg" alt="My Logo" />
<img src="/images/logo.jpg" alt="My Logo" />
<img src="../../images/logo.jpg" alt="My Logo" />
```

If the site always used the full URL like in the first example, you wouldn't have a problem displaying the image. If they used the second one, your site wouldn't be able to find "/images/logo.jpg" on *your* server. You would have to parse all the img elements and prepend the domain. The third example you would have to do even more work by determining the path to the image based on the current URL you were displaying.

Comment: what do you mean by that? sorry, I just started learning rails recently.

Comment: I see. thank you so much for very detailed explanation! ;)